# PostgreSQL: Sum filtered items in a one-to-many relation

Tags: postgresql, join

I have events and sessions associated with them in a one to many relation. I want to make a query to get the amount of past, happening and upcominng events.

- Past events have no active sessions
- Happening events have at least 1 active session
- Upcoming events have sessions in the future

The expected result would be something like:

```
past | happening | upcoming 
-----+-----------+---------
   5 |         3 |       1
```

For simplicity assume the following schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "public"."events" (
    "key" VARCHAR(16) PRIMARY KEY,
    "source" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "created_date" TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "public"."event_sessions" (
    "key" VARCHAR(16) PRIMARY KEY,
    "event_key" VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    "start_date" TIMESTAMPTZ,
    "end_date" TIMESTAMPTZ,
    "created_date" TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT event_sessions_event_key_fkey FOREIGN KEY (event_key) REFERENCES "public"."agenda_events"(key)
);

INSERT INTO "public"."events" ("key", "source", "created_date") VALUES
('uis7r97e2nltmuk9', 'abc', '2023-07-31 10:57:33+01'),
('xe31ha6ejxiuqtob', 'abc', '2023-07-31 10:57:33+01'),
('y7o82e2mczlj6hq6', 'abc', '2023-07-31 10:57:33+01'),
('ysoxj3g8k98hrxow', 'abc', '2023-07-31 10:57:33+01'),
('ysw534pglcya8k01', 'abc', '2023-07-31 10:57:33+01'), 
('yy5qmzu2oecm2il2', 'abc', '2023-07-31 10:57:33+01');


INSERT INTO "public"."event_sessions" ("key", "event_key", "start_date", "end_date", "created_date") VALUES
('pd3htho4wuv6brtp', 'yy5qmzu2oecm2il2', '2023-10-09 00:00:00+01', '2023-10-10 00:00:00+01', '2023-07-31 10:57:33+01', '2023-07-31 10:57:33+01'),
('mbkkbisoclucl8ab', 'ysw534pglcya8k01', '2023-09-22 10:00:00+01', '2023-09-22 13:00:00+01', '2023-07-31 10:57:32+01', '2023-07-31 10:57:32+01'),
('77c6ci6m2zaxfkay', 'ysoxj3g8k98hrxow', '2023-07-21 11:00:00+01', '2023-07-23 20:00:00+01', '2023-07-21 10:36:31+01', '2023-07-21 10:36:31+01'),
('jiy0e2e6wcobwsj5', 'y7o82e2mczlj6hq6', '2023-07-25 00:00:00+01', '2023-07-25 00:00:00+01', '2023-07-21 10:36:28+01', '2023-07-21 10:36:28+01'),
('93nfwtbegkhfyso4', 'xe31ha6ejxiuqtob', '2023-07-26 15:00:00+01', '2023-07-31 01:00:00+01', '2023-07-21 10:36:34+01', '2023-07-21 10:36:34+01'),
('aih5d2e14niqbxe1', 'uis7r97e2nltmuk9', '2023-08-16 01:00:00+01', '2023-08-16 01:00:00+01', '2023-07-21 10:36:34+01', '2023-07-21 10:36:34+01'),
('aih5d2e14niqbxe2', 'uis7r97e2nltmuk9', '2023-08-17 01:00:00+01', '2023-08-17 01:00:00+01', '2023-07-21 10:36:34+01', '2023-07-21 10:36:34+01'),
('aih5d2e14niqbxe3', 'uis7r97e2nltmuk9', '2023-08-18 01:00:00+01', '2023-08-18 01:00:00+01', '2023-07-21 10:36:34+01', '2023-07-21 10:36:34+01'),
('aih5d2e14niqbxe4', 'uis7r97e2nltmuk9', '2023-08-19 01:00:00+01', '2023-08-19 01:00:00+01', '2023-07-21 10:36:34+01', '2023-07-21 10:36:34+01'),
('aih5d2e14niqbxe5', 'uis7r97e2nltmuk9', '2023-08-20 01:00:00+01', '2023-08-20 01:00:00+01', '2023-07-21 10:36:34+01', '2023-07-21 10:36:34+01');
```

I have tried a basic query, and too many variants to show here, but when joining the tables I get the same event multiple times, skewing the results.

```sql
SELECT e.*
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN event_sessions s ON s.event_key = e.key
```

I've tried using subqueries and `LATERAL JOIN` with no success.

```sql
SELECT e.* FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT(event_key)
    FROM event_sessions
    WHERE start_date >= NOW()
) upcoming
JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT e.*
    FROM events e
    JOIN event_sessions s ON s.event_key = e.key
    WHERE
        upcoming.event_key = e.key
        AND start_date >= NOW()
    ORDER BY s.start_date
    LIMIT 1
) e ON true
```

PS: I've been using SQL for only a year and have never needed something more complex that a few joins any help is apreciated. Thank you

Comment: How do you define "happening"? The event only has a single data, it's either has been or will be.

Comment: That's for the session. The event can have many sessions across multiple days. Now that I'm thinking more about the problem it's really hard to define this and I'll have to take a different aproach or just use the solution that you deleted and mark it as accepted

Comment: I'm somewhat confused: you want to count the number of distinct events *not* the sessions? Then how do you deal with an event that has both past and future sessions? And how does that match up with your sample data and expected results? Also extra column in the `INSERT` for `event_sessions`

Comment: Yup that's the problem. I'll have to consider the sessions instead of events. I wanted the stats to match with the total amount of events but it's not realy possible  given your explanation

Comment: I guess you would need to have columns like `EventsWhichSessionsAreCompletelyFinished` `EventsWhichSessionsArePartlyStillUnderWay` `EventsWhichSessionsAreAllInFuture`

Answer (score 1):

This solution consists of two views:

1. **when_sessions**: For each event, count the *sessions* that are past, happening and upcoming.

```sql
CREATE VIEW when_sessions AS
SELECT
    e.key AS event,
    (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM event_sessions
        WHERE NOW() > end_date
        AND event_key=e.key
    ) AS past,
    (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM event_sessions
        WHERE NOW() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date.
        AND event_key=e.key
    ) AS happening,
    (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM event_sessions
        WHERE NOW() < start_date
        AND event_key=e.key
    ) AS upcoming
    FROM events e LEFT JOIN event_sessions s ON e.key=s.key;
```

2. **when_events**: Count the number of *events* that are 'finished', 'happening' or 'upcoming'.

```sql
CREATE VIEW when_events AS
SELECT
    (
        SELECT COUNT(event)
        FROM when_sessions
        WHERE past>0 AND happening=0 AND upcoming=0
    ) AS past,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(event)
        FROM when_sessions
        WHERE happening>0
    ) AS happening,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(event)
        FROM when_sessions
        WHERE past=0 AND happening=0 AND upcoming>0
    ) AS upcoming;
```